# How to name this pattern? Does similar exist? Queue of triggered callback

Tags: design-patterns, callback, queue, eventtrigger

I'll need your help to name or identify existing pattern like that. For the application I'm developing I need to create a queue of callbacks which are fired by an event. Once an event is triggered, consecutive callbacks that are added to the queue are fired immediately.

In the code it would like like that:

```
var queue = new TriggeredCallbackQueue();

queue.onTriggerOrNow(() => console.log('Callback 1')); 
// Nothing is logged to the console

queue.onTriggerOrNow(() => console.log('Callback 2'));
// Nothing is logged to the console

queue.trigger();    // 'Callback1' and 'Callback 2' are logged to console

queue.onTriggerOrNow(() => console.log('Callback 3'));  
// 'Callback 3' is logged to the console

queue.onTriggerOrNow(() => console.log('Callback 4'));  
// 'Callback 4' is logged to the console
```

Do you know if such pattern already exists and is classified anywhere? How would you name it? What do you think about `TriggeredCallbackQueue` name?

Comment: And what does it happen, when you would add `queue.trigger()` after the last line? Does it `console.log` from each callback or nothing happens? If it calls all callbacks, then for me it looks like a `Signal` pattern modified a bit to run Signal Handlers (Callbacks) when the event yet occurred once. I don't know if it has a proper name though. https://github.com/millermedeiros/js-signals/wiki/Comparison-between-different-Observer-Pattern-implementations

Comment: What is the difference of this from waterfall

Comment: @Oskar Once the event is triggered then the callbacks are not queued any more. Thanks for the link, quite useful.

Comment: @LukaszLysik ok so in that case, it's `Promise` design pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises I'll implement that in JS in a little bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's `Promise` design pattern, with slightly changed API:

```js
class TriggeredCallbackQueue {
  constructor() {
    this.promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
      this._res = res;
      this._rej = rej;
    });
  }

  trigger() {
    this._res();
  }

  onTriggerOrNow(cb) {
    this.promise = this.promise.then(cb);
  }
}

var queue = new TriggeredCallbackQueue();

queue.onTriggerOrNow(() => console.log('Callback 1'));
// Nothing is logged to the console

queue.onTriggerOrNow(() => console.log('Callback 2'));
// Nothing is logged to the console

setTimeout(() => {
  queue.trigger(); // 'Callback1' and 'Callback 2' are logged to console
}, 2000);

setTimeout(() => {
  queue.onTriggerOrNow(() => console.log('Callback 3'));
  // 'Callback 3' is logged to the console

  queue.onTriggerOrNow(() => console.log('Callback 4'));
  // 'Callback 4' is logged to the console
}, 4000);

setTimeout(() => {
  queue.trigger(); // Nothing happens
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Good catch @Oskar.